# Multi UI thread in WP8?

Tags: c#, multithreading, windows-phone-8

I want to control some UI elements by a thread and the others by different thread in WP8.
Is there any way to make Muulti UI thread like this? Help me.

Comment: I'm guessing that you probably don't want that, you just think you need it to solve some problem, what you probably want is just to marshal a request to the UI thread to update the data from other threads as needed.

Comment: I really need. I use an API, but it have Thread.sleep() cm. So my app pause. :(

Comment: I use that API to make an UI element :(

Answer (score 3):

In order to update your UI from multiple threads, you can use the Dispatcher

```
Deployment.Current.Dispatcher.BeginInvoke(() =>
{
    // Code to modify your UI
}
```

Comment: That is not I want. I want other UIthread instead of adding element to UIthread

Comment: Oh apologies, I don't think that is possible, may I ask why you want this?

Comment: I use an API, but it have Thread.sleep() cm. So my app pause. :(

Comment: Performing long blocking operations on your UI thread (as it sounds like you are doing with your Thread.Sleep()) is poor design. Could you not off-load this to a BackgroundWorker or something?

Comment: Tks. I use that API to make a UIelement. But that elememt suspend the program, load content from the internet, the program resumed when content loaded

Comment: What is the name of the API you're using, is it public?

Answer (score 0):

As I stated in my comment, I think you're thinking about the problem the wrong way. What you want is not actually to have more than one GUI thread, you just want to do the work on some other thread. Let me illustrate this with some pseudo code (untested):

```
// API method with Thread.Sleep as requested
public static int GetAnswer() {
    Thread.Sleep(5000);
    return 42;
}

// Code assumes to be inside some kind of "Window" class where there is a Dispatcher
public void SomeButton_OnClick(object sender, EventArgs e) {
    Task.Run(() => {
        int answer = GetAnswer();
        Dispatcher.BeginInvoke(() => {
           MyLabel.Text = answer;
        });
    });
}
```

And now for the explanation:
What happens here is that there is some button, that when clicked calls a method (`GetAnswer`) that takes a long time (5 seconds). If that method is called on the GUI thread, the GUI will hang for 5 seconds (not a good thing), so what we instead do is call `GetAnswer` on another thread (using `Task.Run`, other possible ways to do this is with queueing on the threadpool manually, but `Task.Run` has a simple name and is easier to remember when you don't have Visual Studio handy to help you). The thread created by the call to `Task.Run` then starts working on the answer, and after 5 seconds it completes. However, since it's running on a background thread, you can't update the GUI, so therefore (with help of the `Dispatcher`) it tells the GUI-thread to update the the text of `MyLabel` at first chance.

This will give you the ability to call slow methods (either because they do CPU bound work, or they sleep) and then use the result in the GUI.

**[Edit]**
I read your comment about loading content from the internet, and what you probably want to check out is using async API's instead of synchronous ones. Thus you would be able to write code like this without it blocking the UI at all:

```
public async void SomeButton_OnClick(object sender, EventArgs e) {
    // Because we use await here, the GUI thread will not be blocked
    var data = await DownloadFromSomewhereAsync();

    // Once the resource is done downloaded, the rest of the method will run on the UI thread
    MyLabel.Text = data;
}
```

Note ofcause, that in order to use async methods your API needs to support it. Or you could simplify the code I posted in my previous example to this:

```
// API method with Thread.Sleep as requested
public static int GetAnswer() {
    Thread.Sleep(5000);
    return 42;
}

public async void SomeButton_OnClick(object sender, EventArgs e) {
    int answer;
    await Task.Run(() => {
        answer = GetAnswer();
    });
    MyLabel.Text = answer;
}
```

This is because `Task.Run` returns a `Task` that can be awaited.

Comment: Nice! I see. But there is a proplem: loading content and adding UI element in same command :(
VM.Render("3b968291", Grid);
I can't create a Grid outside Dispatcher.BeginInvoke()